# create separate react component for cookie management

Tags: reactjs, cookies, react-cookie

I have a component which renders if its prop.paramA is different from paramA value stored in cookie.

Following is my attempt to move the cookie management logic into a separate component. The problem is that the question component gets rendered only once when showQuestion is false so I never get to see the question.

Currently, my code looks like below

```
// question.js
import React from 'react';
import ToggleDisplay from 'react-toggle-display';
import {withCookies, Cookies} from 'react-cookie';

class Question extends React.Component {

    static get propTypes() {
        return {
            cookies: instanceOf(Cookies).isRequired
        }
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            paramA: props.paramA,
            showQuestion: props.showQuestion
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.state.showQuestion) {
            // do some ajax calls etc.
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="simplequestion">
                <ToggleDisplay show={this.state.showQuestion}>
                    <div>What is your SO profile?</div>
                </ToggleDisplay>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withCookies(Question);
```

I wrote following CookieManager component -

```
// cookiemanager.js
import React from 'react';
import {withCookies, Cookies} from 'react-cookie';

class CookieManager extends React.Component {
    static get propTypes() {
        return {
            cookies: instanceOf(Cookies).isRequired
        }
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        let propA = props.cookies.get('propA');
        if (!propA || propA !== props.propA) {
            props.cookies.set('propA', props.propA, { path: '/', maxAge: 604800});
            console.log('changed', propA, props.propA);
            props.propAChanged(true);
        } else if (propA === props.propA) {
            console.log('unchanged', propA, props.propA);
            props.propAChanged(false);
        }
    }
    render() { 
        return <div id="cookieManager"></div>;
    }
}
export default withCookies(CookieManager);
```

Following is the top level app

```
// app.js
import React from 'react';
import Question from './question';
import CookieManager from './cookiemanager';
import { CookiesProvider } from 'react-cookie';


class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            paramA: props.paramA,
            showQuestion: false,
            avoidUpdate: false
        };
        this.updateShowQuestion = this.updateShowQuestion.bind(this);
    }

    updateShowQuestion(x) {
        if (this.state.avoidUpdate) {
            return;
        }
        this.setState({
            paramA: this.state.paramA,
            showQuestion: x,
            avoidUpdate: !this.state.avoidUpdate
        });
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        if (!nextState.avoidUpdate && nextState.paramA === this.state.paramA) {
            this.setState({
                paramA: this.state.paramA,
                showQuestion: this.state.showQuestion,
                avoidUpdate: true
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <CookiesProvider>
                <CookieManager paramA={this.state.paramA} ridChanged={this.updateShowQuestion}>
                <Question
                    paramA={this.state.paramA}
                    showQuestion={this.state.showQuestion}/>
                </CookieManager>
            </CookiesProvider>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: In other words: you want your `CookieManager` rendered again when cookies change?

Comment: I want the question to get rendered again when cookiemanager changes showQuestion

Comment: Btw, no need to write this in `componentWillUpdate()`: `paramA: this.state.paramA,` in `setState()`. You can leave it out - the old state is kept as is, only the newly passed object is assigned to `state`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading from state here:

```js
<ToggleDisplay show={this.state.showQuestion}>
```

But `showQuestion` is set only once, in the constructor:

```js
this.state = {
    paramA: props.paramA,
    showQuestion: props.showQuestion
};
```

When `this.props` changes your component is rendered, but you're still reading from `this.state` which is not updated, so the visible output is the same.

I see two ways you can solve this:

- Update `this.state.showQuestion` whenever the props change:

  ```js
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
      if(nextProps.showQuestion !== prevState.showQuestion)
          return { showQuestion };
  }
  ```
- In `render()`, read from `this.props.showQuestion`:

  ```js
  <ToggleDisplay show={this.props.showQuestion}>
  ```

  This way may look easier but with the other you gain more fine-grained control over state changes.

---

Another thing you've missed is found here:

```js
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (!nextState.avoidUpdate && nextState.paramA === this.state.paramA) {
        this.setState({
            paramA: this.state.paramA,
            showQuestion: this.state.showQuestion, // this line
            avoidUpdate: true
        });
    }
}
```

You're receiving new props, but you're setting the old state: `showQuestion: this.state.showQuestion`. Instead, set the new `showQuestion` value from the new props - `nextProps`, this way:

```js
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (!nextState.avoidUpdate && nextState.paramA === this.state.paramA) {
        this.setState({
            paramA: this.state.paramA,
            showQuestion: nextProps.showQuestion, // this line
            avoidUpdate: true
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: the rendering condition is: show question if paramA changes compared to its value in cookie else don't show the question. i managed to get cookiemanager get rendered only once but when showQuestion changes, render method of App still not getting called again.

Comment: your suggestion was helpful within Question but not in the parent Component which decides to render Question

Comment: @comiventor I found where you've gone wrong. Edited my answer, hope it is working for you now!

Comment: @comiventor yes you're right I meant `nextProps` but your edit was wrong because there's no `this.nextProps`. Next props are coming from the function argument, not from `this`. I edited my answer correspondingly. It should work now! Let me know if you have any other problems with it.